# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED by docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I'm new to Docker and trying to make a demo Rails app. I made a dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM ruby:2.2 

# Install apt based dependencies required to run Rails as 
# well as RubyGems. As the Ruby image itself is based on a 
# Debian image, we use apt-get to install those.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
  build-essential \ 
  nodejs

# Configure the main working directory. This is the base 
# directory used in any further RUN, COPY, and ENTRYPOINT 
# commands.
RUN mkdir -p /app 
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Gemfile as well as the Gemfile.lock and install 
# the RubyGems. This is a separate step so the dependencies 
# will be cached unless changes to one of those two files 
# are made.
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./ 
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

# Copy the main application.
COPY . ./

# Expose port 3000 to the Docker host, so we can access it 
# from the outside.
EXPOSE 3000

# The main command to run when the container starts. Also 
# tell the Rails dev server to bind to all interfaces by 
# default.
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

I then built it (no errors):

```
docker build -t demo .
```

And then run it (also no errors):

```
docker run -itP demo
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.2.7-p470), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9292
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

When I run a `docker ps` command in a separate terminal to determine the ports, I get:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
55e8224f7c15        demo                "bundle exec rails..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:32772->3000/tcp   ecstatic_bohr
```

However, when I try to connect to it at either `http://localhost:32772` or `http://192.168.99.100:32772` using Chrome or via a curl command, I receive a "Connection refused".

When I run the app outside of docker on my local machine via `bundle exec rails server` command, it works fine. Note that I am using Docker Toolbox on my Win7 machine

What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: You expose port 3000 but you are trying to reach 32772?

Comment: I am exposing 3000 within the container, which is then being mapped to 32772 on my localhost from what I gather (at least per "0.0.0.0:32772->3000/tcp" displayed via "docker ps")

Comment: I normally use docker-compose in conjunction with my dockerfile to make sure things are setup in an automated and consistent fashion.  In your dockerfile you would use the "ports" option and do something like ports: "8000:8000" left 8000 is docker host, right 8000 is docker container.

Comment: @Donald didn't see the port forwarding in the docker run. But have a look into this https://forums.docker.com/t/using-localhost-for-to-access-running-container/3148/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of the above tricks worked--

I had to use `http://<VM IP ADDRESS>:32772` (localhost:32772 did NOT work), AND I had to fix my exposed port to match the TCP listening port of 9292.

I still don't understand why the TCP listening port defaulted to 9292 instead of 3000, but I'll look into that separately.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I spend a couple of hours on this as well and this [thread](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22753#issuecomment-243406719) was really helpful. What i'm doing right now is accessing those services through the vm's ip address.

You can get your vm's address running:

```
docker-machine ls
```

then try to access your service using the host mapped port 37772, something like this:

```
http://<VM IP ADDRESS>:32772
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried this - "docker-machine ls" gives me a URL of "tcp://192.168.99.100:2376". But when I go to "http://192.168.99.100:32772" in my address bar, I still get the same error!

Comment: I saw that you're exposing port 3000 on Dockerfile but your service seems to be listening on port 9292. I think those have to match.

Comment: getting docker-machine: command not found, this is no longer packaged with docker desktop, new syntax is docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id